# MySQL query is very slow

Tags: mysql, temp-tables, bigdata

I have a MySql table that has between 15 million to 20 million rows. I have used data partitioning to improve peformance by over 100% in the past. However, now, when I ran the following query, it took over 60 seconds for the queru to execute.

```
select state, gender, count(*) from big_data where gender in ('Sugar Daddy','Sugar Baby') group by state, gender
```

Result

```
[SQL]select state, gender, count(*) from big_data where gender in ('Sugar Daddy','Sugar Baby') group by state, gender

Affected rows: 0
Time: 59.390s
```

In the explanation I found:
99% of the time was spent copying to temp table! How can I improve performance of this query?

[image]
[image]

Schema & Explain:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For sure using a IN will be slow as it has to do multiple evaluations. Especialy on a string type column. Can't you proceed in an other way? Do you have index defined on your table?

Comment: You need the index (gender, state). Please post table schema and EXPLAIN result.

Comment: Yep, index is defined.

Comment: Ok, wow. When i replaced the 'in' to "select state, gender, count(*) from big_data where gender='Sugar Daddy' group by state, gender" it reduced time down to 27 secondds, from 65

Comment: @Paul: just updated original question with schema and explain. thanks!

Comment: @GautamSharma from the data you've shown, it does not look like the `gender` field is indexed.

Comment: A result from `SHOW CREATE TABLE big_data` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Since an `IN` is really a paraphrased `OR` list, you might try a UNION instead to take advantage of an index on `gender`; like so:

```
select state, gender, count(*) 
from big_data 
where gender = 'Sugar Daddy' 
group by state
UNION
select state, gender, count(*) 
from big_data 
where gender  = 'Sugar Baby' 
group by state
order by state, gender
```

Answer (score 0):

You need at least an index on the `gender` column, so it can be used for the WHERE clause. But if there are too many rows matching the WHERE condition, the sorting for `GROUP BY` might be also expensive. So an index on (gender, state) would be better and your query would operate only that index. Since `state` is already part of the PK, that index wouldn't even take more space, because the PK is always a part of any index in InnoDB.

Additonaly i suggest you to create a `genders` table (gender_id, gender_name), and use a foreign key on your big table referencing `genders.gender_id`. This whay you keep you table and the index smaller.